# Dealing with people modifying ID's in links

Tags: php, security

I'm writing a web app in PHP (using Codeigniter). I'm just wanting some security advice here. I have a task controller with a delete method. The link to delete the task is then http://localhost/task/delete/12345

So I'm wondering how to handle the fact that people have the ability to modify the link, thus deleting another task (probably not their own).

So my options I guess are to always do a check that the user owns that particular task before deleting it, or some sort of ID hashing?

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my options I guess are to always do a check that the user owns that particular task before deleting it

that is the usual, and best, approach, yes. Hashing the ID is too insecure for many use cases: The link containing the hash is stored in the browser's history, might get E-Mailed around, be present in REFERER headers for outgoing links....

Either check ownership, or use a full-blown [Access Control List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list), depending on how complex the permissions are.

Comment: Also, as menhioned by @deceze and @Carlos, make sure you use POST for destructive actions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check whether the user is allowed to delete that task and respond with an
`HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` if he isn't. Also, make destructive actions like deleting records POST requests. Otherwise watch Google (or some other fetcher-type client) happily triggering all your delete actions.

Comment: Thanks, why are post requests a better way to do these actions than http requests?

Comment: Because URLs are easily visited. Search engines follow them. Bookmarks and browser histories save them. POST parameter are not part of the URL and are not saved or followed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

It is not recommended to update/delete your data via an http get request. Use post instead.

Comment: Thats an important point: Some browser prefetch links from the current site to speed up the subjective speed. This may cause a browser to load a "delete"-link and thus accidentally cause the record to get deleted, even if nobody click on it.

Comment: @King Out of interest, can you name any current browser that prefetches links? I think those pretty much died out when broadband caught on. Still a valid point, of course.

Comment: Firefox under some circumstances (others probably too). Some addons for different browser enable this behavior too. At all you cannot rely on, that the browsers _don't_ do it. The bandwidth is not the problem here, but the delay (ping). The subjective speed especially on sites with many external resources (CSS-/JS-files, Images, ..) can get much increased with prefetching independent from the bandwidth of the connection, because the required connections to retrieve the resources are simply already done. Edit, Just to mention: Modern mobile devices have a much smaller line ;)

Answer (score 2):

> So my options I guess are to always do
>   a check that the user owns that
>   particular task before deleting it

Yup, that's it. There's no point in hashing an id, as if some user guesses another hash id he might delete a task from another user (that would be security through obscurity, and it's not a great security method). So, yes, chech that the task belongs to the user before deleting it.

Also, it isn't clear from your question, but to delete something, the user should go to `blablah.com/tasks/delete/1234`, and then confirm to delete the task via POST (submitting a form by clicking a button probably).

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to store the item's id to delete and then on the delete page you check that the id given is equal to the session stored id.

Hope it helps you